# How can I mount a ext4 disk onto a Windows machine?

Tags: windows, mount, disk, ext4

I need to access a disk that is formatted with ext4 on a Windows machine. I will be accessing it within another application so I need it to have a path (such as `D:\`). I have seen several software's claiming to be able to let you interact with it but not get a path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind to use C# or .Net to access ext4 disk, you can try SharpExt4 library

SharpExt4 helps you with Linux file system read and write.

A .Net library to provide full access (read/write) to Linux ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem

Here is the GitHub link https://github.com/nickdu088/SharpExt4